# How to do a regex match on multiple values in fnFilter from Jquery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables

Im' trying to do a filter with multiple values in Jquery datatable but the regex expression is failing.

This works:

```
// $(this).val()[0] = "Testing string";

test.fnFilter("^" + $(this).val()[0] + "$", i, true, true);

This filters all the rows to value "Testing string" for this column.
```

But when I try to do this on multiple values, it is not working properly :

```
// inputValues = "(Testing string|Hello world)"

dossierlijst.fnFilter("^" + inputValues + "$", i, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "(Testing string)|(Hello world)" do? 
I'm heavily relying upon [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/)  for regular expressions myself. Since that eats both groups, maybe JS doesn't like that the brackets are on the outside?

Comment: This should be added as a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Oops - my bad. Can I change that?

Also, I can't comment yet, I need 50 reputation ;_;

Comment: "^(Testing string)|(Hello world)$" only filters the rows on "Testing string"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put ^ before and $ after every value.

```
// inputValues = "(^Testing string$)|(^Hello world$)"

dossierlijst.fnFilter(inputValues, i, true, true);
```

Comment: In the question you've written `"(Testing string|Hello world)"` adding the `^` and `$` in the `fnFilter` function call. This matches exactly what `(^Testing string$)|(^Hello world$)` does. It only captures differently. So there must be some other variable (in `fnFilter` maybe).